# Can a cfg.ini answer file be used during set up of Windows Server 2012 "R2" Essentials

Tags: essentials-2012-r2

Apparently the information in the this link "ONLY" pertains to NON-R2.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2830511

Can "R2" use a cfg.ini answer file in this way?

Or does "R2" use a .xml file and NOT a cfg.ini answer file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not supported in the same fashion as non-R2.

Initial configuration for Windows Server 2012 Essentials R2 setup can be done via PowerShell.

See this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376325(v=wps.630).aspx) for some information on these cmdlets, specifically the `Start-WssConfigurationService` cmdlet.

Comment: Thank you.  No wonder I couldn't get the answer file to work for nothing.  : /